# Proving that $g(x) = \operatorname{sup}_{j}f_{j}(x)$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, functions

I'm studying the proof that $g(x) = \operatorname{sup}_{j}f_{j}(x)$ is measurable. Here, $\{f_{j}\}_{j\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of functions $f_{j}: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$, where $X$ is equipped with the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{X}$. The proof uses:
$$g^{-1}((a,\infty]) = \bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}f_{j}^{-1}((a,\infty]) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Why does (\ref{1}) hold? If $g$ was defined by $g_{k}(x) = \operatorname{sup}_{j \ge k}f_{j}(x)$, would (\ref{1}) become
$$g^{-1}((a,\infty]) = \bigcup_{j=k}^{\infty}f_{j}^{-1}((a,\infty])$$
instead?

Answer (score 1):

Take an element  $x \in g^{-1}((a,\infty])$, then $a < g(x) = \sup_j f_j(x)$ so there exists at least an index $j_0$ such that $f_{j_0}(x) > a$. The converse being also true you have (1).